# Existe uma maneira de salvar um AraayList<Alimentos> no banco de Dados MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, aplicação-web, servlet

Eis minha situação: eu to montando uma aplicação que indica refeições .

Então eu tenho uma tabela chamada alimento, que tem como campos:
idAlimento, nome, medida

Por exemplo:
1 , arroz, 100 gramas
2, feijao, 50 gramas
3, carne alcatra bife, 200 gramas.

Eu quero inserir esses alimentos na tabela refeição, que teria como campos:
idRfeicao, nome, alimentos, tipoRefeicao

Por exemplo: 
1, almoco de segunda, (arroz, feijao, farofa e bife de picanha), almoco

Minha duvida: Eu no caso, so iria inserir o idAlimento na tabela refeição
Porém serão varios idAlimento, que ficarão na mesma linha.

Qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso ?

Eu pensei em salvar o idAlimentos em um arraylist e depois percorrer e salvar eles num campo so da tabela refeicao, mas não sei se essa é a melhor maneira.

Eu queria permanecer num banco de dados relacional, hoje eu to usando o mysql.
Mas se a melhor maneira for um não relacional, como eu faria ?

Obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: O que está acontecendo é que você mapeou o seu relacionamento de 1 para 1, ou seja  cada Refeição tem um e apenas um Alimento, e agora você precisa que Uma refeição tenha vários alimentos. nesse ponto você tem um relacionamento de 1 para N, um para muitos, então você consegue sim programar esse relacionamento usando mysql e java, não é limitação alguma para o banco relacional, inclusive é por isso que ele se chama relacional, espero ter ajudado, se você postar seu código podemos até dar outras dicas e até mesmo corrigir algo que vc deixou passar.

Comment: https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados    /  Normalize a estrutura , senão depois terá sqls complicsdos de forma desnecessária.

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho muito obrigada pela dica
na verdade, essa classe exclusiva, eu nem pensei em como fazer
mas realmente, havia esquecido desse tipo de relacionamento.

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho irei começar pelo DBO com as variaveis e o construtor ..
e volto a postar o codigo aqui
até o momento, agradeço
estou pesquisando sobre o assunto no momento

Comment: agradeço a ajuda de todos
estou salvando o arraylist num arquivo json e depois adicionando no banco de dados
Obrigada !